# Which side has the advantage?

Tags: analysis, endgame

In this game, I made an early exchange of my queen for his rook and bishop.  At the time, I was ahead, though he managed to bring it back to roughly even with an effective threat on the queen side.

Here is the position now.  I traded a knight for his pawn on c7.  White to move; who has the advantage now?  My feeling is this is a draw position, but I'm unsure.

```
[FEN "6k1/Q6p/2P1n1p1/5p2/4r3/8/6K1/8 w - - 1 57"]

1.c7 Nxc7 2.Qxc7 h5
```

Comment: It seems the position you are giving is not quite consistent with the moves... maybe the board is upside down?

Comment: Yeah, I just fixed that!

Comment: White is not going to win this game.  That being said, it's hard to see how Black will avoid a perpetual check. The game will test Blacks _Sitzfleisch_ more than his chess skill.

Comment: That's sort of what I thought (and why I set up the position to allow me to exchange the knight for the pawn - figured that was his only real chance to win was promoting that pawn).  Fortunately for me this is a play-by-phone-app game where *Sitzfleisch* isn't a real problem, just forgetting what I was doing is...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a draw. The only way to avoid perpetual check is to place the rook on f7/g7 and the king on h7. When Black does this, White will put his queen on f6, preventing the pawns from advancing and this is a draw, because Black can only sit in his fortress and repeat moves.

Note that even if Black succeeded in advancing his pawns further it would still be a draw, because that would only make it easier for White to check Black using the squares g8 and h8.